# React-Native: How to nest containers

Tags: react-native

How can I construct container from another containers.
for example:

- containerA - responsible for A
- containerB - responsible for B

Container C - responsible for A + B with different Style C.

in code:

```
class ContainerA extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <ComponentA/>
        )
    }
}


class ContainerB extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <ComponentB/>
        )
    }
}



class ContainerC extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <ContainerA/>
            <ContainerB/>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrap it by a `View` and pass `styles` of `C` like props to `A` or `B`

Comment: thanks for the help.

Comment: I used `Fragment` instead of `View`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to group components in React Native, you can use `View` as such

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'

import ContainerA from './ContainerA'
import ContainerB from './ContainerB'

class ContainerC extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
            <ContainerA/>
            <ContainerB/>
          </View>
        )
    }
} 

const styles = {
  containerStyle = {
    // ...
  }
}
```